# Specify setter method name during Dependency Injection in Spring 3.0

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-3

I am preparing a bean which is present in one of the jars I am using.

The class has setter methods which do not conform to standard setter method name expected by Spring framework to perform injection (e.g. the property `userName` has a setter method `addUserName` instead of `setUserName`).

Is there a way I can specify the setter method name during inject of the properties?

Answer (score 10):

It might be possible to do this using the [MethodInvokingFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MethodInvokingFactoryBean.html) class. With this you can call a method on a target object.

You instantiate your object with Spring and then you call the `addUserName` on it.

I'm not sure if you can do this with annotations, but with XML you can. For example:

```
package some.pack;

public class Target {
  private String userName;
  public Target() {
    ...
  }
  public void addUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
  }
  ...
}
```

You can set the `userName` property on a `Target` instance with something like this:

```
<!-- first create your Target object -->
<bean id="target" class="some.pack.Target" />

<!-- then set the userName property by calling the non-conventional setter -->
<bean id="caller" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
  <property name="targetObject" ref="target" />
  <property name="targetMethod" value="addUserName" />
  <property name="arguments">
    <list>
      <value>John_Doe</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

The downside to this is that if you need to call multiple methods, you will have to add a "caller" bean for each method. This will increase the size of XML you have to write.

Additionally, you could use the [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to wrap your object into something that respects the `getXXX`/`setXXX` convention and do the DI the standard way on the wrapper instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way that I know of.

You can autowire using an annotation.  You can use constructor injection.

I don't see much advantage for breaking the standard, but I see a lot of downside.  What would harm your design if you broke ranks and called the method "setUsername"?

Comment: The problem is the class which I am autowiring is inside a jar. The setters are already designed that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the code of the class you want to instantiate, try using static or instance factory method, where factory is your code that is able to take username as a parameter and call obj.addUsername(name).